# assistance with html code for popup window

Tags: html, popup, window

I will be using shopify's system so i am restricted to how and which pages i can edit.

I have one page that is an app but i want that page, on loading, to show a popup disclaimer before they can see the page.

I am told that i can't edit the app page itself but i can add javascript code in the common site footer to check current url and if it equals this certain page, then create a popup.

I have created a page that holds the disclaimer information so i would like the popup window to load this pages' content.

I believe i can load the content using this div tag

```
div id="popupinfo" pages.disclaimer.content div
```

I do not know how to add the if statement to check if current url = site.com app.html then div id="popupinfo" pages.disclamier.content div

This site uses their own language called Liquid, hence the double brackets..but any code to pull the content of an html page would work i am sure.

Can i please have some assistance in how i am to

1. check current page
2. if page =  xxx
3. best way to create a popup window where the user has to click as yes or ok button
4. then display the regular page

Thanks in advance!

Brocour

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible to open a pop-up window upon a user-action, for example a 'click' action.

Comment: then should i have the link that normally goes to the app instead go to this popup window and when you hit ok or agree then it goes to the app page?  if so what would my code look like ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if( document.URL === "myPage.html" ){
     // Disclaimer alert
     if (confirm('Do you agree to this Disclaimer?')){
         // Redirect
         window.location = "myNewPage.html";
     } else {
         // Do nothing
     }
}
```

Comment: I found out now that i can edit the app page header and footer, just not the body itself.

Comment: So does this If statement change?

Comment: What do you mean by "change" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function poponload()
{
   popupwindow=window.open("","mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=100");
    popupwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
</script>
<body onload="javascript: poponload()">
This is the page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Update....i can edit this app's header and footer only but not the body....this is getting harder and harder i think

Comment: In the header, add a call to an external javascript file.

In the Javascript file, add something like this:
`$(document).ready(function() {
      [...insert window.open here...]
});`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code in [this example](http://jsbin.com/asifob/4/edit) i made.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#open_popup').click(function(){
    popupwindow=window.open("http://google.com","mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=500");
  })
})
```